# Solving for the area between a triangle and a quadratic given tangent point.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

---

QUESTION: For context, this problem has come from a Cambridge Senior Mathematics Methods textbook review test. I am studying for my final school exam and this specific test does not include solutions. Could someone please provide a worked solution.

The straight line $y = -mx + c$ where $c$ is a positive real number and $m$ is a real number such that $0 \lt m \lt 2$, is
tangent to the graph of $y = -bx^2 +d$, where $b$ and $d$ are positive real numbers, at the point $P(2,4)$. The straight line
intersects the $x$ and $y$ axes at points $A$ and $B$ respectively and the area of triangle $AOB$, where $O$ is the origin , is $\frac{50}{3}$

Determine the area of the shaded region in the diagram below:

[image: Diagram representing question]

---

ATTEMPT: Whilst I have ideas that I need to solve for the equation of the quadratic, say $g(x)$, and then solve the for the shaded are by:

$$\frac{50}{3} - \int_O^A g(x)dx$$

However, all my attempts have been unsuccessful

Comment: Isn´t $m$ negative (negative slope)? And why you do not just integrate the tangent to obtain the area of the triangle $A0B$, which is $50/3$?

Comment: @callculus42 the area under the tangent is given

Comment: Yes, it is 50/3. With this value you can set up an equation (area under the tangent line). // OK, you have changed $m$ to $-m$. Now your graph makes sense.

Comment: Try a double integral from the quadratic to the segment and with the second integral from $x=a$ to $x=b$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to do:

1. Calculate the equation of the line. You know it goes through $(2,4)$ and you know the area of the triangle. Calculate intersections in terms of $m$ first.
2. The slope of the line is equal to derivative of the quadratic $g$.
3. The quadratic passes through point $(2,4)$. Together with information from the previous part, this will allow you to determine $g(x)$.
4. Finally, calculate the integral.

If you get stuck, show your work and we might be able to help you in the right direction